# Are QR codes on paper wallets necessary

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet, qrcode

I don't have a wireless printer so I'm thinking about writing down the keys by hand on pieces of paper. Obviously I can't copy the QR codes that way. Are they necessary or do they just exist just for our convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just for convenience.

Make sure to d̶o̶u̶b̶l̶e̶ triple check and use a pen that's readable in ten years, too.